# Django and Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

Hi everybody I'm trying to deploy my website and I'm using AWS S3 to store the images that a user upload. Anyway when I run my website the images don't show up and if I use the inspector I keep having a 404 error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Hope someone can help me, thanks!

And if I open the image in another tab I get this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
</Message>
<RequestId>6F8B0E05F6191EDA</RequestId>
<HostId>
kwKWtzyw9qjLigGQY/QLLBQjfpVmGDKwlt1fUd4Q1pA+LnZ12prqUri7q1MGpc8oAihXFZU08TA=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

The bucket region is UE (London) eu-west-2

This is the CORS configuration I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Normally an xml file starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>` (or some other header with `<?xml ...>`.

Comment: I added the cors configuration I used, the encoding is right?

Comment: The Django code you’re using to store and get the images is relevant here. 404 is not a cors error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `settings.py`, set `AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION` to `s3v4` will work.